# Get numbers from string with regex

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to write a regex to get the numbers from strings like these ones:

```
javascript:ShowPage('6009',null,null,null,null,null,null,null)
javascript:BlockLink('2146',null,null,null)
```

I am having difficulty writing the regex to grab these numbers.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
(\d+)
```

What language are you using to parse these strings?

If you let me know I can help you with the code you would need to use this regular expression.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming:

- you want to capture the digits
- there's only one set of digits per line

Try this:

```
/(\d+)/
```

then `$1` (Perl) or `$matches[1]` (PHP) or whatever your poison of choice is, should contain the digits.

Answer (score 7):

Integer or float:

```
/\d+((.|,)\d+)?/
```

Answer (score 0):

just match numbers: \d+

Answer (score 0):

```
// PHP

$string = 'ssss 12.2';
$pattern = '/\D*(\d+)(.|,)?(\d+)?\D*/';

$replacement = '$1.$3';

$res = (float)preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

// output 12.2
```