# regex for finding numbers inside a string

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get numbers from string with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043619/get-numbers-from-string-with-regex)

Hi I need to check if a string is in the following format.

> case1/clientid2

In the example the case and clientid will be static but  numbers will change. Is it possible using Regular expression?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried, and what language are you using?

Comment: Your example doesn't clearly explain the string format, but it looks like you might be able to do your thing in a simpler way than using a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, definitely duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043619/get-numbers-from-string-with-regex).

Here's the regex that you could use, `case[\d]+/clientid[\d]+`

**Edit**: Removed the escape character.

Comment: No need to escape the '/', it has no special meaning in a regex. Well, unless the language you use requires that you escape it, and even then , the escape character may not be a backslash.

Comment: True that, I use [this](http://myregextester.com/index.php) website and I have set up my default escape character to be '/'.