# How do I create an XPath query to extract a substring of text?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create xpath so that it only returns order number instead of whole line.Please see attached screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is [the substring-after() function](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp) -

> fn:substring-after(string1,string2)
>
> Returns the remainder of string1 after string2 occurs in it
>
> Example: `substring-after('12/10','/')`
>
> Result: '10'

For your situation -

`substring-after(string(//p[contains(text(), "Your order # is")]), ": ")`

To test this, I modified the DOM on this page to include a "Order Number: ####" string.

See it in action:
[image: Screenshot of the DOM]
[image: Me using the same function to extract a similar string]

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use your normal Xpath selector to get the complete text, being "Your oder # is: 123456" and then perform a regex on the string like mentioned in [Get numbers from string with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043619/get-numbers-from-string-with-regex)

Comment: This would be far more overhead and far more code than the pure-XPath approach, though. Is there any specific benefit for this approach?

Comment: @MichaelWard Would it? RegEx has a reputation for being slow, but this doesn't actually need a RegEx (if it _did_, I'm not sure you could do it in XPath!). Meanwhile XPath is notoriously opaque. Retrieving the whole node and then doing substring searches seems likely to be easier to maintain and I doubt slower.